# Pop-up ' Don't show this message again ' option

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm not sure if this will be possible on Tumblr .  The popup I have isn't a ' fancybox' . I've tried finding a solution here but I haven't had much luck . I have a pop-up box that is displayed when a visitor comes to my blog , but whenever I click the next page -- it pops up again . I do not want it popping up every time someone refreshes . I want it so it pops once every 7 days per user and it has a ' do not display message again ' option for them.

This is the script.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var id = '#dialog';


//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();


//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').show(1000);
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.5);

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).show(2000);  

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();


$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});


//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide();
});




});

</script>
```

This is the close button

```
<a href="#" title="close" class="close"><div class="rotating" style="margin-    left:395px; margin-top:-25px; position:absolute;"><big>✦</big> </div></a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use cookies or sessions on your website so that you can track which users have seen pop-ups.

In this case I would probably recommend HTML5 webstorage.

[HTML Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

You can then store an item relating to your popup with an expiry date that you can check or set every time before showing a user a popup.

Hope this helps.